# Passing Parameters by url

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a question about web apps in Google Script. For example: I created a web app based on a form with some 4 text fields and my final link is something like this: 
    https://script.google.com/macros/s/xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz/exec

So, I want to know if it's possible to open the web app (form) with pre-filled textfields, for instance, the 4 textfields will have the values: 10,20,30 and 40.

I try something like this:
https://script.google.com/macros/s/xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz/exec?txt1=10

Can you recommend me a way to do that?

Regards,

Comment: you are close. inspect the e param in your doGet(e) and you will find the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As Zig Mandel suggests in his comment, the `e` event object of the `doGet(e)` or `doPost(e)` functions has specific parameters as defined in [this Google Apps reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). You could use `e.parameters` to access the parameters passed to the web app via the URL query string.

However, if the values are known in advance, wouldn't it be better to pre-fill the text fields via the HTML of your web app? Something like:

```
<input type="text" name="txt1" value="10" >
<input type="text" name="txt2" value="20" >
<input type="text" name="txt3" value="30" >
<input type="text" name="txt4" value="40" >
```

I may be misunderstanding your exact context, but this would be an easier approach.